# How to add a texture to the emitter surface of a hair particle object (over riding object material)

Tags: texturing, particles, hair

I'm trying to make carpet with a pattern. I applied an image texture to a particle emitter and it looks okay. [image: carpet with image texture applied to particle emitter]

However I want the carpet strands to be more realistic so I made an object to emit instead..
[image]

But now I'm at a loss as to how to apply the pattern texture to the whole carpet again because the strands now take their material from the single object.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign the material to the particle, put the base object in the Texture Coordinate node and you can use Object Coordinates this way.

[image]

For reference, without:
[image]