# Hair particles rendered as objects using the emitters material for color. Is it possible?

Tags: particles

I'm trying to make a stylized soccer field with grass.
I have a simple plane with a material that contains a grass texture and soccer field lines.[image]

I'm attempting to make my grass with hair particles rendered as objects using the plane as my emitter. I have another simple plane that I want to use as my grass strand object.
**So far so good.**

I need the grass strands (hair objects) to get their color from the emitters material, depending on their position, so that the grass particles on top of the field lines are white.

This works by default when using hair particles rendered as paths.[image]

But not when hair particles are rendered as objects.[image]

Is this doable with hair particles rendered as objects?
(I don't really care if I have to use Eevee or Cycles)

Comment: Does this help you? [How to add a texture to the emitter surface of a hair particle object (over riding object material)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/203035/107598)

Comment: Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)