How to texture particle object hair
I generated some low poly fur using hair particles and a single triangle object


How can i sorta "sample" the texture underneath the particle object origin, and color the entire triangle in the color of that "sampled" pixel?

Here is a similar question (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/203035/how-to-add-a-texture-to-the-emitter-surface-of-a-hair-particle-object-over-ridi). But the question mentions an Image Texture while the accepted answer uses a procedural Noise Texture with object coordinates and no UV map. I guess that won't work for you :-(
